# Error with PIL import Image, and pytesser import

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am new to Python. I am attempting to create a Python OCR program, and am following a tutorial online for it. Here is the recommended code I use:

```
from PIL import Image
from pytesser import *

image_file = 'menu.tif'
im = Image.open(image_file)
text = image_to_string(im)
text = image_file_to_string(image_file)
text = image_file_to_string(image_file, graceful_errors=True)
print "=====output=======\n"
print text
```

The tutorial link is found [here](http://www.manejandodatos.es/2014/11/ocr-python-easy/). I am getting this error when running this code however.

```
    from pytesser import *
ImportError: No module named 'pytesser'
```

I have followed the instructions, from installing OCR [here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract) and the PyTesser library here code(dot)google(dot)com/archive/p/pytesser/downloads (sorry because <10 rep i can't post more than 2 links).

This (see gyazo below) is a screenshot of my installation files so far, where "pytesser_v0.0.1" is my pytesser folder, "tesseract-master" was found on GitHub (probably not relevant), and "tessinstall" is the folder where I installed tesseract and finally pyimgr.py is my file I am attempting to run.

gyazo(dot)com/333f8a3333e87895558f26875a8a8487

I was also previously getting an error regarding PIL import Image. I should not be using PIL, so is there any other way I can import Image without PIL? maybe pillow?

My Python version is 3.5.2 and I am using windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

My first hunch is that your library is installed in a place that Python does not know.

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

If you execute those lines in Python it will show you where Python will look for eggs. Is the pytesser lib there?

Furthermore: As a side note:
`pip3 search tesseract` will show you some other tesseract Python packages. So you can use the Python package manager.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to this:

```
"""OCR in Python using the Tesseract engine from Google
http://code.google.com/p/pytesser/
by Michael J.T. O'Kelly
V 0.0.1, 3/10/07"""

import PIL.Image
import subprocess

import util
import errors

tesseract_exe_name = 'tesseract' # Name of executable to be called at command line
scratch_image_name = "temp.bmp" # This file must be .bmp or other Tesseract-compatible format
scratch_text_name_root = "temp" # Leave out the .txt extension
cleanup_scratch_flag = True  # Temporary files cleaned up after OCR operation

def call_tesseract(input_filename, output_filename):
    """Calls external tesseract.exe on input file (restrictions on types),
    outputting output_filename+'txt'"""
    args = [tesseract_exe_name, input_filename, output_filename]
    proc = subprocess.Popen(args)
    retcode = proc.wait()
    if retcode!=0:
        errors.check_for_errors()

def image_to_string(im, cleanup = cleanup_scratch_flag):
    """Converts im to file, applies tesseract, and fetches resulting text.
    If cleanup=True, delete scratch files after operation."""
    try:
        util.image_to_scratch(im, scratch_image_name)
        call_tesseract(scratch_image_name, scratch_text_name_root)
        text = util.retrieve_text(scratch_text_name_root)
    finally:
        if cleanup:
            util.perform_cleanup(scratch_image_name, scratch_text_name_root)
    return text

def image_file_to_string(filename, cleanup = cleanup_scratch_flag, graceful_errors=True):
    """Applies tesseract to filename; or, if image is incompatible and graceful_errors=True,
    converts to compatible format and then applies tesseract.  Fetches resulting text.
    If cleanup=True, delete scratch files after operation."""
    try:
        try:
            call_tesseract(filename, scratch_text_name_root)
            text = util.retrieve_text(scratch_text_name_root)
        except errors.Tesser_General_Exception:
            if graceful_errors:
                im = PIL.Image.open(filename)
                text = image_to_string(im, cleanup)
            else:
                raise
    finally:
        if cleanup:
            util.perform_cleanup(scratch_image_name, scratch_text_name_root)
    return text


if __name__=='__main__':
    im = PIL.Image.open('phototest.tif')
    text = image_to_string(im)
    print text
    try:
        text = image_file_to_string('fnord.tif', graceful_errors=False)
    except errors.Tesser_General_Exception, value:
        print "fnord.tif is incompatible filetype.  Try graceful_errors=True"
        print value
    text = image_file_to_string('fnord.tif', graceful_errors=True)
    print "fnord.tif contents:", text
    text = image_file_to_string('fonts_test.png', graceful_errors=True)
    print text
```